# certbot installation on CentOS 8 fails

Tags: linux, centos, python, certbot, dnf

Trying to install certbot on CentOS 8 with `sudo dnf install certbot python3-certbot-nginx`, as suggested at [certbot's website](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/centosrhel8-nginx) fails with the following error

```
Error: 
 Problem 1: package python3-certbot-nginx-1.3.0-1.el8.noarch requires python3.6dist(certbot) >= 1.1.0, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package python3-certbot-nginx-1.3.0-1.el8.noarch requires python3-certbot >= 1.0.0, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides python3-mock needed by python3-certbot-1.3.0-3.el8.noarch
  - nothing provides python3.6dist(mock) needed by python3-certbot-1.3.0-3.el8.noarch
 Problem 2: package certbot-1.3.0-3.el8.noarch requires python3-certbot = 1.3.0-3.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides python3-mock needed by python3-certbot-1.3.0-3.el8.noarch
  - nothing provides python3.6dist(mock) needed by python3-certbot-1.3.0-3.el8.noarch
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Adding `--nobest` to the command, as the last errorline suggests, did not work.

Epel-Release and python3 were installed previously.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable the PowerTools repo which holds the required dependencies:

```
sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled PowerTools
```